# Is it possible to select multiple markers in a dojo chart and pass their coordinates to an event?

Tags: charts, dojo, markers, dojox.charting

[image: this is an example of what I am trying to achieve]

I want to select two or more markers in a chart and perform an action using their coordinates.
Selecting the points is the main problem since I didn't find anything on this topic and I'm not sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in a Pie Chart.

What I did was use "connectToPlot" to change the series color when the user click on it.

This is a resume of the work that I did: [change series color when user click on it](http://jsfiddle.net/noeliasfranco/3zdkG/)

See that when you click on the serie, the color changes to gray and if you click again the series returns to it original color (saved it in the attribute "originalColor").

```
pieChart.connectToPlot("default", function(evt) {

                var shape = evt.shape;
                var type  = evt.type;

                if (type == "onclick") {
                     var fillColor = "rgb("+shape.fillStyle.r+", "+shape.fillStyle.g+", "+shape.fillStyle.b+")"; console.log(shape.fillStyle);
                    if(shape.rawNode.getAttribute("originalColor")==null)
                        shape.rawNode.setAttribute("originalColor",fillColor);

    var strokeColor = "rgb("+shape.strokeStyle.color.r+", "+shape.strokeStyle.color.g+", "+shape.strokeStyle.color.b+")";

                   if(fillColor=='rgb(238, 238, 238)'){
                        shape.setFill(shape.rawNode.getAttribute("originalColor"));
                        shape.setStroke(shape.rawNode.getAttribute("originalColor"));
                   }else{
                        shape.setFill('rgb(238, 238, 238)');
                        shape.setStroke(shape.rawNode.getAttribute("originalColor"));
                   }
                }
```

Comment: Your code is a good starting point. i will use the "connectToPlot" to store the coordinates in an array and, after selecting the last point, perform the action using the array. Thanks, Costel

Comment: I kind of resolved it by creating a svg rectangle (the blue rectangle in the drawing) inside the svg container of the chart, and comparing each point in the chart to the rectangle boundaries.